# Como comparar duas imagens com PHP?

Tags: php

Existe alguma ferramenta ou forma de criar uma comparação de imagens com o PHP? Preciso que o sistema identifique quando uma imagem não é igual a outra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comparação de imagens no php é utilizado com a biblioteca [imagemagik](http://br.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compareimages.php)
da seguinte forma

```
<?php

$image1 = new imagick("image1.png");
$image2 = new imagick("image2.png");

$result = $image1->compareImages($image2, Imagick::METRIC_MEANSQUAREERROR);
$result[0]->setImageFormat("png");

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $result[0];

?>
```